# How to run the .reg file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

I want to run the .reg file (registry file) using PowerShell Script but I am not able to run it. When i run it manually it creates the respective nodes in registry but i want it execute using powershell script.
Below is the code which i tried using but got no results -

```
$PathofRegFile="c:\file.reg"
regedit /s $PathofRegFile
```

Another code which i tried was this -

```
Start-Process -filepath "C:\windows\regedit.exe" -argumentlist "/s c:\file.reg"
```

Please Help..!

Below is the Content of my .reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP]
@=""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP\Platform]
"VERSION"="8.2.6.0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP\Platform\AppService]
"MONITORINTERVAL"=dword:00000005
"MONITORAPPS"="STEP Audit"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP\Platform\Audit]
"TRACEON"=dword:00000000
"TRACEDIR"="Specifies the directory to dump trace files if TRACEON is set to 1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP\Platform\Common]
"SSMITRACEFILEX"="C:\\Program Files\\SePI\\STEP\\LogFiles\\SSMITraceFile.txt"
"SSMILOGERRORSLOCALLY"="Yes"
"SSMIDoNotSendToAudit"="FALSE"
"ResourceFile"="C:\\Program Files\\SePI\\STEP\\Programs\\"
"REPORTALLEXCEPTIONS"="Yes"
"KSPath"="C:\\Program Files\\SePI\\STEP\\KeyStore\\"
"KEY"="10069356713705F858B56A9E850DD8CB7D"
"intelliSUITEnode"="WebApp"
"InstallationDir"="C:\\Program Files\\SePI\\STEP\\"
"IMSFirstRun"=dword:00000001
"CONFIGPATH"="C:\\Program Files\\SePI\\STEP\\Configuration Files\\"
"COM_VERBOSEGLOBALCACHE"="False"
"COM_UserProfileCacheExpirationInSecs"="30"
"COM_SSMISenderUtilCacheExpirationInSecs"="120"
"COM_REPORTIGNOREDEXCEPTIONSASWARNINGS"="True"
"COM_LOCALUTILSCACHEEXPIRATIONINSECS"="600"
"COM_DEFAULTPROPERTYCACHEEXPIRATIONINSECS"="600"
"ProductName"="Ron"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP\Platform\ESI]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP\Platform\ESI\ITranQueryPrep]
"PATH"="C:\\Program Files\\SePI\\STEP\\QueryTemplates"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP\Platform\ITran]
"MAXROWSTORETURN"=dword:000003e8
"WRITERPSWD"="PASSWORD"
"WRITER"="ITRAN_WRITER"
"SERVER"="SQL SERVER"
"READERPSWD"="PASSWORD"
"READER"="ITRAN_READER"
"DBNAME"="DATABASENAME"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SePI\STEP\Platform\ReportingSvc]
"STATUSINTERVAL"="5"
"POLLINTERVAL"="2"
"MONITORINTERVAL"="5"
"MAXWORKERTHREADS"="5"
"CONFIGFILE"="C:\\Program Files\\SePI\\STEP\\Configuration Files\\"
```

Comment: Do you get errors?

Comment: No I dont get any Errors

Comment: $S=Start-Process -filepath "C:\windows\regedit.exe" -argumentlist "/s "/s c:\file.reg" -PassThru -Wait 

  $S.ExitCode -eq 0                                                                                  This is how i used and it returned True on my command shell. Is this the way i should use exitcode?

Comment: @SRP If regedit exits with 0, it means the merge was successful.

Comment: Is this a x64 bit machine? Perhaps the reg is loaded into the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How about using reg.exe instead of regedit.exe

```
Get-Command reg

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     reg.exe                                            10.0.16... C:\Windows\system32\reg.exe
```

this worked for me fine:

```
reg import .\test.reg
```

Comment: .\ refers to current folder, in your case you should use absolute path so the command would be "reg import C:\file.reg"

Comment: @ Aurimas N, I tried using it in this way-    reg import C:\Demo.reg   It worked and in registry it created the node but on Command Shell it gave this message in RED colour -           reg : The operation completed successfully.
At C:\Suraj\AutoServerRoleScript.ps1:77 char:1
+ reg import C:\Demo.reg
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The operation completed successfully.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: it seems that RED message is only happening in ISE, you may try `start-process reg -ArgumentList "import C:\Demo.reg"`

Comment: I keep receiving this error:
reg : ERROR: Error opening the file. There may be a disk or file system error.
At line:1 char:1
+ reg import "~\AppData\Local\WinDynamicDesktop\scripts\MouseScript\Dar ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Error op...e system error.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: maybe there is an actual problem with the disk, try running `chkdsk c: /f` to see if there are any problems reported

Answer (score 9):

I use

```
Invoke-Command {reg import \\server\share\test.reg *>&1 | Out-Null}
```

the last part

```
*>&1 | Out-Null
```

pipes the output to null so the console doesn't see it.  I do not think this is required but it annoyed me.

Answer (score 7):

You may be trying to run it with insufficient privileges.  This snippet should work:

```
$startprocessParams = @{
    FilePath     = "$Env:SystemRoot\REGEDIT.exe"
    ArgumentList = '/s', 'C:\file.reg'
    Verb         = 'RunAs'
    PassThru     = $true
    Wait         = $true
}
$proc = Start-Process @startprocessParams

if ($proc.ExitCode -eq 0) {
    'Success!'
}
else {
    "Fail! Exit code: $($Proc.ExitCode)"
}

Pause
```

Comment: I tried using this code on Command Shell it display the Success! but in Registry the node is still not created.

Comment: @SRP It then sounds like the problem is with your registry file.  Post the content in your question.

Comment: I have posted the content of the reg file in the question above, please have a look.

Comment: `Start-Process` returned `$null` when used with `reg.exe` so there is no `ExitCode` property to check

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
Start-Process -filepath "$env:windir\regedit.exe" -Argumentlist @("/s", "`"C:\file.reg`"")
```

Comment: This worked the best for me by far.

Comment: How does invoking `regedit` via the CLI with a flag differ to `reg import`?

Comment: @baltermia it's a lot more code, what's the upside?

Comment: no idea tbh I can't really remembmer but I guess it was the only working solution for me

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

> regedit /s "c:\file.reg"