# How do i Run powershell with elevated credential in the script then execute files in their locations

Tags: powershell

I want to execute 3 different files when I click on the .ps1. I want it to already have the elevated credentials within

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(".administrator", (ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force))

Start-Process CMD.exe -Verb runAs -PassThru 

Get-Item -FilePath '\\I:\Mo Khalifa\eBillingHub\utils\addper.bat'

Get-Item -FilePath '\\I:\Mo Khalifa\eBillingHub\utils\AddToTrustedSites.reg' 

Get-Item -FilePath '\\I:\Mo Khalifa\eBillingHub\utils\DotNetPermissions.reg'
```

I don't know if its doing anything

Comment: FYI above script isn't meant to work i just need help structuring it properly

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Start-Process` instead of `Get-Item` for your bat file:

```
Start-Process c:\path\to\file.bat
```

You can also use the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676660/how-to-run-the-reg-file-using-powershell) question to use your reg files:

```
reg import .\path\to\reg.reg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your credentials with the `-Credentials` parameter. It will impersonate the user to run the commands.

So in your .ps1 script, you could add the `-Credentials $credential` in the PS Cmdlets that you're calling.

````
-Credential <PSCredential>
        Specifies a user account that has permission to perform this action. Type a user name, such as User01 or
        Domain01\User01, or enter a PSCredential object, such as one from the Get-Credential cmdlet. By default, the
        cmdlet uses the credentials of the current user.```
````